# Scanning an image for a certain color to exist

Tags: java, colors, pixel

I'm trying to code a program that helps me checking if there's a certain color in any pixel of an image.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    try {
        //read image file
        File file1 = new File("./Scan.png");
        BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(file1);

        //write file
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("log1.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        for (int y = 0; y < image1.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < image1.getWidth(); x++) {

                int c = image1.getRGB(x,y);
                Color color = new Color(c);

                if (color.getRed() < 50 && color.getGreen() > 225 && color.getBlue() > 43) {
                    out.write("Specified Pixel found at=" + x + "," + y);
                    out.newLine();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get it to run, so I'd love to get some hints on how to do this the right way.

Comment: Specifically what do you mean by "I can't get it to run"? Does it build? If it builds, what does it do?

Comment: What the error you got

Comment: "The method getRGB(int, int) in the type BufferedImage is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Comment: Actually i got it build now. Yet it doesn't output me anything

Comment: Maybe your choosen color never found try to print something into the console to see if the color exist

Comment: @marcelxvi Take a look at my solution below. It should be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code. It actually works. You just have to ensure the image you are using is having the same color intensity as you are expecting in your codes.

For example, a (seemingly) red pixel may not necessary be `RGB (255, 0 , 0)`. The image format may plays a part too.

If you use lossy compression image formats (e.g. jpeg, png), the color pixels might be altered during the saving process.

I tested your codes on 24bit-bitmap, it is able to output something. You can test it on some basic color first:

**Example:**

```
if(color.equals(Color.RED))
    System.out.println("Red exist!");
```

Comment: **Remarks:** I just did another test, it works on lossy image formats as well. Then I am more certain now that the image you used for testing probably does not contains a color pixel which matches the stated color intensity in your condition.

Comment: @marcelxvi Check your image and let me know whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

---

Maybe it throws iOException try this one why would you throw an exception that you already try catch it

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
        //read image file
        File file1 = new File("./Scan.png");
        BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(file1);

        //write file



        for (int y = 0; y < image1.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < image1.getWidth(); x++) {

              int c = image1.getRGB(x,y);
              Color color = new Color(c);

               if (color.getRed() < 50 && color.getGreen() > 225 && color.getBlue() > 43) {
                    System.out.println(x + "," + y);


                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pixel value can be received using the following syntax:

```
Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
```

You can then call your getRed()/getGreen()/getBlue() methods on c.

Comment: just changed it to be outgoing from c. It didn't fix my problem tho, still no output

Comment: Add an else statement on your if function to print something if no pixels are found that match. It's possible the image you are scanning has no pixels that match the one you're checking for.